# Variable is not being set properly

Tags: linux, sh

Whenever I try to use one variable to build another I get unexpected results.  I've narrowed it down a bit but could use a little help on what's happening here.  My local script does this:

```
CUR_TIME=$(date "+%Y%m%d_%HH%MM%SS")
CUR_TIME="build_"$CUR_TIME
```

That gives me the desired results.  However, whenever I try to use this to build another variable or echo something containing this variable:

```
echo "/home/path/blah/$CUR_TIME"
```

My result only echos the `$CUR_TIME` variable back.  What is happening here?

The `$CUR_TIME` variable is set on my local shell session, I'm getting additional variables from a remote server via ssh like this `additional_vars=$(ssh user@server "cat variables.properties")`

I then do `eval $addtional_vars`.  The `$additional_vars` includes quite a few variables and echoing them individually works fine.

So I then build or echo out the new variable using this format:

```
echo "/home/path/blah/$additional_var1/"
```

This echoes properly, but if I do this (reverse):

```
echo "/$additional_var1/home/path/blah"
```

My result is just `/home/path/blah`.

**EDIT**

After further troubleshooting it looks like if I include *any* of my vars from `$additional_vars` to the path name and put it before anything I specify, it results in that part of the path being null.  So it's not just the `$CUR_TIME` variable.  What's weird is that echoing out an `$additional_var` by itself is fine.

My .properties file looks like this:

```
var1="something"
var2="something2"
var3="something3"
var3="ftp://something/another/$something_else"
var4="something.something"
```

If I test `eval $additional_vars` using `printf ${additional_vars} | hexdump -C`, my output results in a hex value and then `|var1="something".|`

Comment: Do you have any ANSI escape sequences in your `${additional_var}`iables? Can you provide a specific, minimal example that fails on you which you can post the contents of the variables of?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth No, I do not.  :-/

Comment: And there's really just one slash in your output?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth sorry, I'm slow... can you please elaborate on your question a little?

Comment: I would assume that because I can echo out any `$additional_var` that I should be able to just use it as I would any variable.  Every single one of my variables is set properly using `eval`.

Comment: I mean that you do not get `//home/path/blah` which would be the expected result in case the variable expands to an empty string. Pretty certain it doesn't - otherwise you wouldn't ask this question - but just to make sure.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth there is no extra slash.  It looks like whenever I try to combine any of the variables I got using `eval $additional_vars` parts of them will be cut off.  This doesn't happen when they are echoed separately.

Comment: Does `printf "${additional_var1}" | hexdump -C` look ok?

Comment: Great test!  Testing with that command shows that something is wrong.

Comment: Can you post the actual output on your terminal? This is pretty hard guesswork here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I was doing was this:

```
additional_vars=$(ssh user@server "cat variables.properties")
```

If I then echoed this variable it showed a multi-line variable containing this information:

```
var1="something"
var2="something2"
var3="something3"
var3="ftp://something/another/$something_else"
var4="something.something"
```

So there were some odd things happening when I was running `eval $additional_vars`, which appeared to be going line by line and assigning the variables assigned in `variables.properties` because if I then echoed the variables it was fine.  But using them gave the interesting results I mentioned in my post.

I ended up doing this to get it to work:

```
additional_vars=$(ssh user@server "cat variables.properties")

printf %s "$additional_vars" | while IFS= read -r line
do 
    eval $line
done
```

This cleared up every issue, but I'm not sure why this works over the other way.

Alternatively, one can also do the following:

```
for line in $additional_vars
do
   eval $line
done
```